# How to avoid overlapping of items in a QComboBox dropdown, with a large font size

Tags: qt, qcombobox, qtstylesheets

I would like to use a large font size with a `QComboBox`. I tried setting the font-size using a style-sheet:

```
*{font-size: 22pt}
```

This does change the font size, but the spacing between the items in a `QComboBox` drop-down end up overlapping. How can I get a large font and also get the proper row spacing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Styles for the drop down of a `QComboBox` can be changed by applying relevant changes to **QComboBox QAbstractItemView** as showed in the following example:

```
QComboBox QAbstractItemView
{
   color:#ccc;
   background-color:#333;
   border:none;
   selection-background-color:#1c1c1c;
   selection-color: #ccc; 
   height: 30px;
}
```